# Are there any mobile-friendly tree components using vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a library similar to jsTree that is mobile-friendly (works with fat fingers, touch for drag-n-drop and so on) and does not rely upon any Javascript frameworks such as jQuery, Vue or React.

I am open to implementing this without a library as well, but I'm not sure that it's necessarily easy to do.